Is it possible to have more than 10 lines in the stack trace of Jasmine/Karma?
I use Jasmine/Karma for unit tests in Angular.
When there's an error in a test, the maximum number of lines in the stack trace is 10 and I would to like to increase it (in order to know what test fails).
Does anyone know?
An example of stack trace:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unknown')
    at Function.isUnknownType (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/client/app/Types/type.ts:48:51)
    at Function.getMinIdxUnknownTypes (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/client/app/Types/type.ts:325:14)
    at TypeEquation.getMinIdxUnknownTypes (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/client/app/Types/type-equation.ts:222:4)
    at TypeEquationsSystem.computeMinIdxUnknownTypes (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/client/app/Types/type-equations-system.ts:258:14)
    at new TypeEquationsSystem (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/client/app/Types/type-equations-system.ts:49:9)
    at TypesDescription.getCorrespondingTypeEquationsSystem (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/client/app/WorksInProgress/TypedWorks/TypesDescription.ts:2055:10)
    at TypesDescription.updateArraysUsable (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/client/app/WorksInProgress/TypedWorks/TypesDescription.ts:1819:47)
    at new TypesDescription (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/client/app/WorksInProgress/TypedWorks/TypesDescription.ts:46:8)
    at TypesDescription.newTypesDescriptionInference (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/client/app/WorksInProgress/TypedWorks/TypesDescription.ts:1713:13)
    at TypesDescription.useDefineFunctionInference (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/client/app/WorksInProgress/TypedWorks/TypesDescription.ts:907:18)

